# Heap Organaziation with CMD - Paramters

Tags: windows, assembly, parameters, heap-memory, abi

I have the following question:

Assume I have a 64-bit Windows machine.
I call an application with the command line parameter "xyz".
How will my heap looks like. I understand that the string will be stored in the heap and the address will be stored in the stack.

Will it use 64 bits for one character or how is it organized?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think command line arguments are stored on the stack on Windows.

Comment: command line arguments are stored on the stack, because the number of arguments varied from 1 to 4 and it works regardless of how many parameters you declared in your source code file https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#C_and_C++

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the heap in assembly.
Under Windows, the command line is stored somewhere<sup>1</sup> and the application can get a pointer to it with `GetCommandLineA` or `GetCommandLineW`.
Note that the arguments are not processed like they are in C or Linux, the command line is a single string.

`GetCommandLineA` returns a string of 8-bit bytes using the encoding of the system, such as CP1252.
`GetCommandLineW` returns a string of UTF16 code-units and so it is locale independent.

Note that the command prompt font lacks the glyph for a few symbols (e.g. for `€`) using the replacement character `?` but the byte/code-units are correctly handled.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's in the `_RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` structure in the `PEB`, as a `UNICODE_STRING`. It gets converted by the `DllMain` of `kernelbase.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

String representation in a heap is dependent on a codepage that was used by the executable, without regard to a bitness.